# Input type = Registration number

Tags: android

How do I set the input type for registration number. For example my university has specific format for registration number i.e. CIIT/SP17-mcs-044/Atk. I want CIIT/ATK is written already and Sp17-mcs-044 as a hint.

Comment: this is not related to input types

Comment: As @Tim has stated, the input type would be text over here and when user types in that `EditText` then check if the input is correct by using RegEx, and then show any message when the input is correct

Comment: Input type does not provide field validation, it only set up android virtual keyboard layout to insert (for example) a number, a date or a simple text field. If you need to validate your input you'll have to use a regex

Comment: Now, `CIIT/ATK` can be a `TextView` placed right before the `EditText` so it will be written already and will be uneditable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim has stated, the input type would be `text` over here and when user types in that `EditText` then check if the input is correct by using RegEx, and then show any message when the input is correct, for that you will need to add an `OnTextChangedListener`, about which you can learn more on official documentation.

Now, `CIIT/ATK` can be a `TextView` placed right before the `EditText` so it will be written already and will be uneditable. And yes, add that in final string after getting the input, like this:

```
finalInput = "CIIT/ATK" + input;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a random types of input type. You can only have one of [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType) types as `inputType`.

If you want any custom behaviour, you might use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) and validate it